# How to use MySQL UNION inside UNION ALL

Tags: mysql, sql, union, union-all

I am trying to execute this query:

```
(
SELECT co.id as offerId, co.title, co.details, co.link, co.reference, co.rank
FROM club_offer co
WHERE co.id IN (31, 791, 360, 382)
GROUP BY offerId
UNION
SELECT co.id as offerId, co.title, co.details, co.link, co.reference, co.rank
FROM club_offer co
WHERE co.id IN (869, 376, 201, 1246)
GROUP BY offerId
ORDER BY rank DESC
)
UNION ALL
(
SELECT co.id as offerId, co.title, co.details, co.link, co.reference, co.rank
FROM club_offer co
WHERE co.id IN (117, 168, 193, 204, 330, 377, 378, 379, 380, 381, 452, 931, 980, 1100, 1146, 1147, 1190, 1247)
GROUP BY offerId
ORDER BY rank DESC
)
```

But I get error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'UNION

So, I guess that either I am using wrong syntax or I am trying to do something that can not be done. I guess that SQL fiddle is not needed for this, most likely experienced people will see right away what is wrong.

Can someone help ? Thanks

Comment: Remove the `ORDER BY`s

Comment: Why GROUP BY when no aggregate functions are used? Besides, can MySQL have column aliases in the GROUP BY?

Comment: This query is part of much bigger one, and I use group by to remove dupicate values, DISTINCT do not help.

Comment: Yeah, as @jarlh said, remove the `GROUP BY` too, you are even using the alias of the column instead of the column names

Comment: Removing them gives the same error.

Comment: then maybe you have other errors on the rest of the "much bigger" part of the code

Comment: The syntax is Core ANSI SQL-99 compliant (with ORDER BY removed.) But can't you merge the 3 SELECT's into 1? It's basically the same query over and over again.

Comment: Try `(
SELECT co.id as offerId, co.title, co.details, co.link, co.reference, co.rank
FROM ...
UNION
SELECT co.id as offerId, ...
) t
UNION ALL
(
SELECT co.id as offerId ...
)`

Comment: @jarlih, there are different joins in each of them. to Lamak, I am trying this query without order and group inside phpmyadmin, I am not trying the bigger one.

Comment: @artm , thanks for try, but it doesn't help.

Comment: Maybe you can not use UNION inside UNION ALL ?

Comment: The issue is with your parentheses -- try this working fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f6702/7

Comment: @sgeddes : Unknown column 'id' in 'field list'

Comment: @black-room-boy -- um, that's just sample data -- perhaps your query would use `offerId` instead...

Comment: @sgeddes Thank you ! * worked, and I will later try to customize so I do not select all. It work ! Thanks Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is coming from your parentheses.  Here's one way to rewrite your current query:

```
SELECT offerId, title, details, link, reference, rank
FROM
(
   SELECT co.id as offerId, co.title, co.details, co.link, co.reference, co.rank
   FROM club_offer co
   WHERE co.id IN (31, 791, 360, 382)
   UNION
   SELECT co.id as offerId, co.title, co.details, co.link, co.reference, co.rank
   FROM club_offer co
   WHERE co.id IN (869, 376, 201, 1246)
) t
UNION ALL
SELECT co.id as offerId, co.title, co.details, co.link, co.reference, co.rank
FROM club_offer co
WHERE co.id IN (117, 168, 193, 204, 330, 377, 378, 379, 380, 381, 
                452, 931, 980, 1100, 1146, 1147, 1190, 1247)
ORDER BY rank DESC
```

- [Condensed Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f6702/7)

I've removed the `group by` and `order by` clauses from the inner queries as well -- feel free to add back as needed, but the `order by` in the subquery would be useless.

Answer (score 0):

You are using parentesis in a wrong way: the way you put in your code seems that you are trying to establish precedence order between selects unioned statmets, and that is not allowed by the syntax. But as was mention by some one on the coments, you can:

```
select * from
    (select ... from ...
    union
    select ... from ...) as T1
union all
    select ... from ...
```

Where all sides of union/union all are single queryes.

Some minor issues:
`order by` inside each select has no sense if no limit clause is present.
not in all cases `group by` (using mysql hability to miss grouping functions) results the same result that `distinct`